# Serving static assets during development with WebPack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm new to WebPack and React, and am having an issue getting my settings correct.

My directory structure is:

```
/project/
  /src/
    index.html
    app.js
  /static/
    /images
```

My "output" WebPack config section is:

```
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
},
```

My React app runs fine, but I'm not getting any images served with urls as such:

```
<img src="/static/images/logo.jpg" />
```

If I change the image `src` values to:

```
<img src="/src/static/images/logo.jpg" />
```

they work, but of course, that's not going to be the case in production, since the `/src/` directory wouldn't be deployed. It seems I have the root set incorrectly.

Do I need to tell WebPack to copy the "static" directory into "dist"? or? Advice appreciated.

Comment: The path of images in src tag is always relative to index.html file

Comment: That's true, however, if I set the `src` of the image to: `static/images/logo.jpg` which is a relative, not absolute path, the image isn't loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging, what I actually wanted was: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base

Then I modified my npm start script to:

```
"./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --content-base src/"
```

and now relative image paths are happy again.

Answer (score 2):

You can `import` (or `require`) images with webpack.

Add the `file-loader` to the webpack config (make sure `file-loader` is installed):

```
{
  test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/,
  include: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'static')
  ],
  loader: 'file',
}
```

You can then `import` an image:

```
import Image1 from '../static/images/image1.png';
```

and use it like this:

```
<img src={Image1} width="64" height="64" />
```

Webpack will place all imported images in the "dist" directory.

Comment: I suggest adding `$` to your file loader test, otherwise it might match files containing but not necessarily ending with png. `test: /\.(png|gif|jpg)$/`

Comment: Is there an advantage importing images via WebPack versus serving them directly from Apache or Nginx?

Comment: I've confirmed that this does in fact work, but not all of my image paths are importable. Some come from REST calls, and I can't modify the src attribute of those objects.

Comment: @Brandon You can actually do both - `import` images and use Apache or Nginx to serve the content of the webpack's output folder.

Comment: Cool. I thought so. I guess the real problem I'm experiencing is what the WebPack development server considers the root. It seems that the dev server is considering my project directory the webserver root instead of the "dist" or "src" directory.